# Inserir timer perl

Tags: timer, perl

Estou precisando colocar um timer nesse perl abaixo:

Ele funciona disparando email seguidos ate o final da lista de emails.

Exemplo se a lista tiver 1 mil emails ele dispara email por email ate acabar.

Eu gostaria de colocar um timer nesse codigo

EX: disparar 500 emails a cada 30 segundos. Seria possivel ? desde já agradeço a atenção.

Segue abaixo o código ou no https://pastebin.com/nj8bYyZ8

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
#by IV ' lost
use MIME::Base64;
$ARGC=@ARGV;

if ($ARGC !=4) {
  printf "$0 <mailist> <remetente> <assunto> <fake.htm>\n\n";
 exit(1);
}

$sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';

$sender = $ARGV[1];

$subject = $ARGV[2];

$efile = $ARGV[0];

$emar = $ARGV[0];

open(FOO, $ARGV[3]);

@foo = <FOO>;

open (BANDFIT, "$emar") || die "Can't Open $emar";

$cont=0;

while(<BANDFIT>)        {
($ID,
 $options) = split(/\|/,$_);
chop($options);
  foreach ($ID) {
$r2 = int(rand(99));
$r3 = int(rand(999));
$r4 = int(rand(9999));
$r5 = int(rand(99999));
$r6 = int(rand(999999));
$r7 = int(rand(9999999));
$r8 = int(rand(99999999));
$r9 = int(rand(999999999));
$recipient = $ID;
$corpox = join("\n", @foo);
$corpox =~ s/%email%/$ID/g;
$corpox =~ s/%rand1%/$r1/g;
$corpox =~ s/%rand2%/$r2/g;
$corpox =~ s/%rand3%/$r3/g;
$corpox =~ s/%rand4%/$r4/g;
$corpox =~ s/%rand5%/$r5/g;
$corpox =~ s/%rand6%/$r6/g;
$corpox =~ s/%rand7%/$r7/g;
$corpox =~ s/%rand8%/$r8/g;
$corpox =~ s/%rand9%/$r9/g;
$corpo = encode_base64($corpox);

$subject =~ s/%email%/$ID/g;
$subject =~ s/%rand1%/$r1/g;
$subject =~ s/%rand2%/$r2/g;
$subject =~ s/%rand3%/$r3/g;
$subject =~ s/%rand4%/$r4/g;
$subject =~ s/%rand5%/$r5/g;
$subject =~ s/%rand6%/$r6/g;
$subject =~ s/%rand7%/$r7/g;
$subject =~ s/%rand8%/$r8/g;
$subject =~ s/%rand9%/$r9/g;

$sender =~ s/%rand4%/$r4/g;

open (SENDMAIL, "| $sendmail -t");
print SENDMAIL "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
print SENDMAIL "Content-type:  text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
print SENDMAIL "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
#print SENDMAIL "$mailtype\n";
print SENDMAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
print SENDMAIL "From: $sender\n";
print SENDMAIL "To: $recipient\n";
print SENDMAIL "$corpo\n\n";
close (SENDMAIL);

$cont=$cont+1;
printf "$cont * Enviado para > $recipient";

}

}

close(BANDFIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Miguel,
Se eu bem entendi, pretendes fazer pausas, (para não saturar o sistema?).

Se assim for, tenta algo como juntar um pequeno `sleep(x)` em cada envio ( sendo x em segundos),

```
#...ciclo de envio{
# ...enviar mail
       sleep(2);
#...}
```

ou um grande sleep ao fim de cada 500

```
#...ciclo de envio
#...  enviar mail
      $cont=$cont+1;
      printf "$cont * Enviado para > $recipient";
      sleep(30) if $cont % 500 == 0;
#...
```

Por último considera a hipodese de usar Mail::Sender

```
 use Mail::Sender;
 $sender = new Mail::Sender {smtp => 'mail.yourdom.com', from => 'tu@address.br'};
 $sender->MailFile({to => 'some@address.com',
      subject => 'Here is the file',
      msg => "I'm sending you the list you wanted.",
      file => 'filename.txt'});
```

Comment: Joao poderia dar o exemplo no codigo ? por favor que ta dando erro aqui.

Comment: Onde está a dar erro? --> juntar a linha `sleep(30) if $cont % 500 == 0;` após o printf?